# Sphinx `make html` fails with symbol not found error

Tags: python, ctypes, python-sphinx

I am trying to use Sphinx to produce documentation for a small set of Python files that exists within a larger source code repository. The source uses `ctypes` to load `GetInfo` and `AddInfo` symbols from the current process, which is supposed to be a *GoLang* executable.

```py
parent = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(None)

parent.GetInfo.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]
parent.GetInfo.restype = ctypes.c_char_p

parent.AddInfo.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_int]
```

When I run `make html` from within the sphinx docs folder I receive the following error:

```
AttributeError: dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, GetInfo): symbol not found
```

I think that this is because the GoLang executable is not running within the Sphinx process.

The C header file is available that defines the symbols for *GetInfo* and *AddInfo*

```
#ifndef A_COPROCESS_API
#define A_COPROCESS_API

struct CoProcessMessage {
  void* p_data;
  int length;
};

extern void addInfo(char* key, char* value, int ttl);
extern char* GetInfo(char* key);

#endif
```

Is there are way to get Sphinx to load the symbols from the C header file or, alternatively, mock the dependency introduced by the following?

```py
parent = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(None)
```

Comment: The functions are *extern*. They most likely reside in a *so*, and that's the one you should load.